# Can't Bind name property of Pivot Item to label text in pivot header template

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I have a Pivot control that uses a Datatemplate as header

In the property UriSource of the BitMapIcon AppBarButton I have binded the  header property of the pivot item and I would like to bind in the Label text of the AppBarButton the property Name of the Pivot Item.
Is possible to do this? Or how can I bind label text from the pivot item as I binding the Header to the UriSource?

```
<PivotItem  Width="360" Name="Home" Header="ms-appx:///Assets/AppBar/Home.png" DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel.HomeModel}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource HOMEList}" />


<DataTemplate x:Key="PivotHeader" >
  <Grid  Background="{StaticResource AppForegroundColor}">
    <AppBarButton Label="{Binding Name}">    (doesn't work)
      <AppBarButton.Icon>
        <BitmapIcon  UriSource="{Binding}"/> (gets header prop)
      </AppBarButton.Icon>
    </AppBarButton>
  </Grid>        
</DataTemplate>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:

It was easy.

I've just created a class with text and image properties in the Datacontext viewModel of the pivot control and binded the object to the header property of the pivot item.

Thanks